# Oracle Encoding: Can't Replace Vertical Bar / Pipe due to non-ascii values

Tags: oracle, replace, ascii, etl, utf

I'm trying to deal with ETLing a table in Oracle that happens to have 20 columns and three of them happen to be clobs. I'm most comfortable using '|' as my delimiter however I came across a column with the following data '¦1XYZ' when I query it. The most interesting part is when I did a replace/regex it did not alter the pipe. I did a rawtohex and it came out with the value: 'C2A631464753'. Is there any way to deal with the true value 'Â¦1XYZ' ?  (no luck with converting/translate)

I couldn't use SSIS to pull the Oracle data down to a flat file due to the utf characters.  I'm at the point of using sql*plus spooling then using Teradata TPT to upsert.  Beyond desperate at this point since I'm behind on my timeline.

Yes, the rawtohex and Â¦1XYZ does not match exactly for company data purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing all the (`¦`) characters with a pipe (`|`) first?

Something like this:  (here `A6` is a hex representation of the  `¦` character)

```
select replace('¦1XYZ',utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('A6')),'|') from dual
```

Of course you would run the `replace` on whole original string.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow morning. I never saw utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('A6')),'|').  Thanks for the idea!